# Where to save macros in Spacemacs?

Tags: macros, spacemacs

It's a rather simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

The Emacs documentation suggests to save macros in the .emacs file. Is there a convenient way to save macros in Spacemacs? Which file should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. You can save your macros :

- in your `.spacemacs` file, in the `dotspacemacs/user-config` function
- in a private configuration layer (see [documentation](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#managing-private-configuration-layers))